# Perl and MongoDB: Inserting Array of Objects into Key-Value Pairs

Tags: perl, mongodb

I'd like to insert into my MongoDB using perl the following BSON structure:

```
{"name" : "BOB", "stuff" : [{"area1": [1,2,3,4,5]}, {"area2": [5,6,7,8,9]}]}
```

But have had a hard time finding a good example of this. I tried the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use MongoDB;
use MongoDB::Database;
use MongoDB::OID;

my $conn = MongoDB::Connection->new;
my $db = $conn->test;
my $users = $db->real_time10;


$users->insert
({
    "name" => "BOB",
    "stuff" => 
              "area1" => [1,2,3,4,5],
              "area2" => [5,6,7,8,9]
});
```

Which grossly outputs upon query in the mongo shell:

> db.real_time10.find()

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fc912fa000207ec08000000"), "ARRAY(0xa5bdd4)" : "area2", "A
RAY(0x2f2e844)" : null, "name" : "BOB", "stuff" : "area1" }
```

What is going on? Is there a simple way to do this?

My dream/desired output would be:

```
> db.real_time10.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fc912fa000207ec08000000"), "stuff" : {"area1" : [1,2,3,4,5],   
"area2": [5,6,7,8,9]}, "name" : "BOB" }
```

Comment: See my updated answer, but looks like you figured it out yourself. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, it's this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use MongoDB;
use MongoDB::Database;
use MongoDB::OID;

my $conn = MongoDB::Connection->new;
my $db = $conn->test;
my $users = $db->real_time10;


$users->insert({
    "name" => "BOB",
    "stuff" => 
          {"area1" => [1,2,3,4,5],
          "area2" => [5,6,7,8,9]}

});
```

This outputs:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fc91f110064e9d40b000000"), "name" : "BOB", "stuff" : { "are
a2" : [ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ], "area1" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] } }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your missing your anonymous-array-constructor (square-brackets) in your example code - but including them in your BSON example. To get your desired output try:

```
$users->insert({
    "name" => "BOB",
    "stuff" => {
        "area1" => [1,2,3,4,5],
        "area2" => [5,6,7,8,9]
    }
});
```

By excluding the array constructor it builds up a hash with the supplied array key, value pairs so it would be parsed as the following (which matches your data-dump):

```
{
    "name" => "BOB",
    "stuff" => "area1",
    [1,2,3,4,5] => "area2",
    [5,6,7,8,9] => undef
}
```

Note: an array-ref in scalar context will be seen as a string like "ARRAY(0x6052b8)"

Comment: Cool - this is closer to what I want and now I understand my strange output. That being said, when I query my DB i now get this:


`> db.real_time10.find()`
`{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fc91d0600eaf50408000000"), "name" : "BOB",` `"stuff" : [ "are`
`a1", [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], "area2", [ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ] ] }`


This seems to be more like an array that contains arrays than an array of objects that correspond to key value pairs. I will update the question with my dream output, haha.